# Need detailed instructions to install Scribus 1.5.5 from tar.xz to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, development, scribus

Yes, This is the dev version. Need to open & edit old .pub files. I have looked at several how to install from tar.xz,gz,etc - all just confusing.  Have downloaded the tar.xz and extracted the files to a folder on my desktop. Need very clear instructions how to proceed. I am not very familiar with terminal commands.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Ubuntu 20.04 comes with the exact same version of Scribus in the repositories so, if you have 20.04 or newer save yourself the trouble and install normally.

Comment: If, let's say, you're running Ubuntu 18.04 just add this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~scribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa Again, no need to be compiling from source.

Comment: Or the AppImage: https://sourceforge.net/projects/scribus/files/scribus-devel/1.5.7/scribus-1.5.7-linux-x86_64.AppImage/download

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18.04  (Wasta).  What is  PPA?

Comment: A .tar.xz (tarball) is not a software *package*. It's just a bunch of random files zipped together. You must *install* those files manually, usually using instructions included in the tarball -- a README or INSTALL file. You must also *uninstall* those files manually. Tarballs are rather tedious and annoying to use for software distribution, which is why we stopped using them over 20 years ago in favor of automatically-installable software *packages*. Since a package is available, and much easier, we suggest using it.

Comment: There is a ReadMe file, but it only gives what is new in this version, no install info.  There is no INSTALL file.  So where do I find an installable package for Scribus 1.5.5 for Ubuntu 18.04 ? The latest stable release version 1.4.x  is not able to open or edit Publisher files. Version 1.5.5 is the most stable developer version that will work for Ubuntu 18.04 that can process .pub files. Unless the 1.5.6 version for Ubuntu 20.x  works properly on 18.04?

Answer (score 3):

The tar files contain the source code that you can compile and it's probably not meant for the average user.

If you just want to run Scribus 1.5.x on Ubuntu you have several options that provide you with executables (PPA, appimages).

But, if you have a look at [https://launchpad.net/~scribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Escribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you will see that 18.04 has no packages available for the latest releases of Scribus.

That's because it's not easy to get the latest Scribus to work on a three years old Ubuntu (the main reason being that you will need to upgrade Qt and that might break other packages).

The latest 1.5.6svn provided there for 18.4 should be enough to simply read .pub files, but you should be aware that it's an older snapshot.

To get it open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt remove scribus
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install scribus-trunk
```

So, if you want the latest Scribus, you should probably upgrade your Ubuntu to the latest release.
Scribus 1.5.6svn or 1.5.7 should then be available from the normal repositories.
If you have no experience with compiling, it will be much faster than trying to use the tar file or otherwise finding workarounds that let you use a current Scribus on your current system.

And for the other readers, if you really want to compile Scribus, you'd better take the source code from the SVN org Git repositories, not from the tar.
(As I wrote above, the tar file is not meant for the average user: it's only / mostly for people who are preparing packages and for archiving purposes.)